# Format NSString using NSFormatter

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting price of an object in string and I want to formate it as currency.
I am using the following code:

```
var priceString : NSString = urlDict.objectForKey("price") as NSString 
var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let priceNumber = formatter.numberFromString(priceString)
```

I am getting the data fine in priceString but priceNumber is `nil`.

And if I try this:

```
var priceNumber : NSNumber = urlDict.objectForKey("price") as NSNumber
```

then also the priceNumber is `nil`.

What approach should I take to achieve a formatted price from the string?

Comment: I just tried your code setting priceString = "$12", it works correctly and the output is 12. try it on playground

Comment: @eridb I just tried 'let priceNumber = formatter.numberFromString("123456")' in the playground and its returning 'nil'

Comment: @sasquatch you have told it that the formatter you are giving it is a currency string. Therefore you need the $ at the beginning. (Or whatever the currency is).

Comment: as @Fogmeister mentioned, you need to add currency symbol on the string in order to use `CurrencyStyle` for `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for the suggestions:
I have combined above solutions to form a function:

```
 func formatAsPrice(priceString: NSString) -> NSString { 
    let rsSymbol = "\u{20B9}" // The currency symbol for India
    var priceStrTemp = priceString
    priceStrTemp = rsSymbol + priceStrTemp
    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_IN") //Explicit
    formatter.secondaryGroupingSize = 2  // grouping as Indian currency style

    let priceNumber = formatter.numberFromString(priceStrTemp)!
    var finalPrice: NSString! = (rsSymbol + " \(priceNumber)") as NSString!

    return finalPrice

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Formatter code is fine.
You have to pass correct Currency string with currency symbol

```
func format(amount: String) -> NSNumber? {
  let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
  formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
  formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
  return formatter.numberFromString(amount)
}
format("NOK 12,00") // returns 12.00
format("NOK 12") // Also fine
format("$ 12") // Error, my local currency is NOK (Norwegian krone)
format("12,00") // Error, needs currency symbol in the string.
```

If you want to parse trying without currency sublime like this `"12,00"` that you should set `currencySymbol` to empty string. Like this

```
func format(amount: String) -> NSNumber? {
  let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
  formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
  formatter.currencySymbol = ""
 ...
}

format("12,00") // Works fine now
```

Comment: I am from India. What is the correct currency string?
I tried "Rs. 1234" but still 'nil'

Comment: I think your currency code is "INR" try like this format("INR 12,00")

Comment: No, still 'nil'..:(
Is there any document pointing Currency strings?

Comment: Tried setting currencySymbol to empty string. Still 'nil'

Comment: you can change you local. formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_IN");
here is a list of identifiers
https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273